# Scipy Write Audio Issue

Tags: python, audio, scipy, scikit-learn, signal-processing

I'm doing an ICA application where I aim to separate signals from within a mixed signal observation. It seems to work in theory, when I look at the ICA recovered signal in numpy ndarray from, the signal is clearly visible. However, when I try to write this ndarray to a .wav for play back, the signal disappears altogether. This can be easily seen in the following picture:
[image]

The first graph shows the numpy ndarray signal of the ICA recovered signal. The second graph shows where I simply loaded the file that was supposedly written by scipy .wav write, as you can see it's silent.

This behavior is puzzling because earlier on I used the exact same procedure in generating my mixed signal observations using a mixing matrix (also in the same format, numpy ndarrays). In the following picture, you'll notice every thing is exactly the same, and yet, for whatever reason, the scipy write .wav *worked* -- the second graph does verify the signal was loaded from the .wav that was written from the first graph (the numpy nd array).

[image]

I'd like to know what's behind the conditional success for this. I know that floats and integers need to be handled carefully, but I'm pretty sure I have not overlooked anything.

The pictures explain it pretty well, the only thing I'd like to clarify is what the `play_wav` function is doing, it basically just writes the .wav and creates an audio object:

```
def play_wav(file, fs, data):
    wavfile.write(file, fs, data.astype(np.dtype('i2')))
    display(Audio(filename=file))
```

imports:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.io import wavfile
from IPython.display import display, Audio
from sklearn.decomposition import FastICA
```

Comment: You haven't show the function `load_wav`.  It would help if you could provide a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we could copy and run to recreate the issue.

Comment: Fair point, here is a repository with my entire jupyter notebook. Upload speeds are low at the moment, there is only 1 .wav that I used available on this link. I will try to update it soon to include all 3 .wavs. You could use your own .wavs if you wanted. Of course, if you just wanted to see the inner workings of things, you can just view the notebook ipynb file. Here it is: https://github.com/diggetybo/ICA-Attachments

Comment: Ok, all 3 .wavs are there now. If someone wants to 100% re-create my procedure, that would be possible now. Place the .wavs in the jupyter notebook directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as though the array you're trying to write contains values in the range [-0.02, 0.02]. When you cast the array to 16bit ints before writing it to the WAV file, all of these values will be truncated to zero!

`wavfile.write` supports float32 arrays, so you could just skip the casting step altogether. Alternatively, rescale the array to fall between 2<sup>15</sup> and -2<sup>15</sup> before casting it to int16, e.g.:

```
((data + data.min()) * (2 ** 15) / data.ptp()).astype(np.int16)
```

Comment: Great work ali_m, you found the problem! I probably would never have noticed that. Just out of curiosity, why did you choose 2^15? Is it because that way it would interpolate them to close to their original levels? So you knew their original levels from looking at the 'true signal' from the .wavs at the beginning of the notebook, I'm guessing? I ask because I want to write that line for the general case, in which case I might need a formula for which base and which magnitude to use. or is 2^15 a standard of some sort?

Comment: A 16 bit signed integer can represent values between 2^15 (actually 2^15 - 1) and -2^15. There are 15 bits to encode the magnitude of each integer then one bit for its sign. When you cast from floats to integers every value in your array will be rounded down to the nearest integer. By scaling the values to fill the range of representable integers you can minimize the loss of precision due to this rounding.

Comment: Makes total sense now, couldn't have got this working without you!